# Groovy , parse html with XmlSlurper , how to get the html code in a node?

Tags: groovy, html-parsing

i am parsing an html page using XmlSlurper and HtmlCleaner, i have the GPathResult with

```
def page = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(xml)
```

now i can use GPath to access the various nodes.

In the html i have a paragraph like this one:

```
<p>
 some_text1
 <br />
 some_text2
 <br />
 some_text3
 <br />

 ....
 some_textN


 <br />
</p>
```

the problem is that now i don't know how to parse the text in the paragraph, i need to split the text inside the paragraph using the `<br />` tag as separator and get a list like

```
[some_text, some_text1, some_text2, .... ,some_textN]
```

Having the node like

```
def node = page.body.some_path.p[0]
```

if i use text() i get all the text in the paragraph but without the `<br />` so i cannot use the split method, and i don't find a way to get the real html inside the paragraph from the node.

There is some way to parse this text?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem in the past with GPath and couldn't really find a good way to go about it either.

What I ended up doing is a search/replace for `<br />` in this case, replacing it with something that isn't an XML element.  Call it `REPLACEMENT_SEPARATOR`.

That way, you could call `node.text().split(REPLACEMENT_SEPARATOR)` and get your array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, seems the only workaround for doing this. In you code you mean  node.text().split(REPLACEMENT_SEPARATOR) right?